# Neural Net with batch size 1 and one input at a time

Tags: autoencoder, tiny-dnn

I tried a very simple autoencoder, 3 inputs, one layer with 2 neurons and the out put with 3.
Just numbers

```
0.01    0.02     ...........    1.0
0.011   0.021                   1.01
0.012   0.022                   1.02
```

That works if all samples, 100, are the input and with 200 epoches.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            samples[i][0] = (float)(i+1) * 0.01;
            samples[i][1] = (float)(i + 1) * 0.01 + 0.01;
            samples[i][2] = (float)(i + 1) * 0.01 + 0.01 + 0.01;
        }
    }

net.fit<mse>(optimizer, samples, samples, 100, NUM_EPOCHS
        , onMinibatch, onEpoch);
```

But feeding one sample at a time doesn't work.
Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_EPOCHS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            samples[0][0] = (float)(j + 1) * 0.01;
            samples[0][1] = (float)(j + 1) * 0.01 + 0.01;
            samples[0][2] = (float)(j + 1) * 0.01 + 0.01 + 0.01;

            net.fit<mse>(optimizer, samples, samples, 1, 1
                , onMinibatch, onEpoch);
        }
    }
```

Is it that bad to feed single samples into a neural network?
Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake, use

```
net.train_once<mse>...
```

does the job.